# Detect if dynamically created HTML form has completed submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, dynamic

I'm creating a form tag and submit it with certain data, to download a file without reloading the entire page.

Form tag is made invisible and appended to the body element.

```
        var frm = $('<form />');
        frm.attr('method', 'POST');
        frm.attr('action', url);
        frm.attr('display', 'none');
        $(document.body).append(frm);
        frm.submit();
```

Everything works fine, except that after some time I see these invisible forms accumulating in the body element, even after their work is done, wasting memory.

How can I programmatically detect that form's work is done, and destroy the form element?

I understand that I can use a timeout with a reasonable delay to do this, but need to know if there is a better way? Perhaps by using a IFRAME?

Comment: Would an ajax request not be more suited for that purpose. There you have callback functions to do exactly what you want. I think that is the way jquery and other tools are doing it and there is no such attribute to check if a form has been submitted on the server.

Comment: `frm.attr('display', 'none');`, i guess you mean `frm.css('display', 'none');`

Comment: @Koogle Ajax requests work if I want to get some data down, here I want to download a file and I want the browser to show the 'Save As' dialog. That doesn't happen if I use the normal Ajax request. That's the issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff well, it works with attr as well. But I agree css is a better alternative.

Comment: I don't know any attribute `display` but as your FORM is empty, there is no purpose to set its display property anyway

Comment: `How can I programmatically detect that form's work is done` Bind onsubmit event (delegated or not) to the FORM. But i'm not sure what is your issue. Could you replicate it?

Comment: But can't you just submit the form data via post and then use  done() to show your Dialog.

Comment: @A.Wolff, Thanks for the tips. But my issue is something else. I don't need to use onsubmit, I submit the form myself in code. I need to know when the request has completed, not when it's sent. :)

Comment: Which request are you talking about? Submiting FORM should be synchronous

Comment: t0 --> I create a form.
t1 --> I submit it.
t2 --> File download begins.
t3 --> File is completly downloaded.
I need to be notified at t3. :)

Comment: Could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download